# Jquery .css to change one style

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-link', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
        $(document).find("#followdiv").( "top", "0px" );      
});
```

I am trying add a style to `<div id="followdiv">` so that it becomes `<div id="followdiv" style="top: 0px;">`. I used this http://api.jquery.com/css/ as reference for the code above and I dont know why it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $('.close-link').on('click', function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().remove();
        $('#followdiv').css( "top", "0px" );    
    });
});
```

Your `div` has an id so you can target it directly with jQuery.
Also you don't have to use `.parent().parent().parent().parent()`, there is **[`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** you can use

Comment: i have tried using that also, all examples in http://api.jquery.com/css/  were tried, but none of it works...

Comment: Instead of chaining these `parent()` calls. Is there no way to select the element you want? I.e. name, id or class?

Comment: @BeldionBryanBalanan https://jsfiddle.net/tdw56fn3/ look at the fiddle. It is working so your problem must be somewhere else. May wrap your code in `$( document ).ready()` ?

Comment: `.parents()` will select all parents that match the selector. You should propose [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) instead.

Comment: @VisioN true, but I propose `parents()` with the combination of a selector like `.parents('div')`.

Comment: @laaposto That's what I mean. `.parents('div')` will select all `<div>` parents of `this` element, whereas `.closest('div')` will select only the first one, what the OP obviously wants to achieve.

Comment: this edited codes, actually worked, but what exactly was my mistake here? I was following the jquery api documentation and doesn't know why it didn't work...

Comment: @VisioN we can only assume what OP wants without HTML markup. I assume that `$(this)` has only one ancestor `div`. But in any case `closest()` is covering all cases, so its better

Comment: @laaposto Yeah, and it will be faster for this scenario.